# Ошибка в обновлении рекламных обьявлений

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Использую метод для [редактирования объявлений](https://vk.com/dev/ads.updateAds).

В ответ получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
 ["error_code"]=>100
 ["error_msg"]=>"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: data[data][ad_id] is invalid"
```

Сам массив data:

```
string(185) "{"data":{"0":{"ad_id":"15142751","cpc":4.4},"1":{"ad_id":"15142643","cpc":4.4},"2":{"ad_id":"15210287","cpc":4.4},"3":{"ad_id":"15210280","cpc":4.4},"4":{"ad_id":"15210269","cpc":4.4}}}"
```

ID объявлений верны, скорее всего я неврно формирую массив объектов.

```
  $data = json_encode(array('data' => $data), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Полный ответ с ошибкой:

```
 array(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["error_code"]=>
    int(100)
    ["error_msg"]=>
    string(84) "One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: data[data][ad_id] is invalid"
    ["request_params"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(5) "oauth"
        ["value"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(6) "method"
        ["value"]=>
        string(13) "ads.updateAds"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(10) "account_id"
        ["value"]=>
        string(10) "xxxxxxxxxx"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(4) "data"
        ["value"]=>
        string(151) "{"data":[{"ad_id":22981362,"cpc":4.4},{"ad_id":22975854,"cpc":4.4},{"ad_id":22721708,"cpc":4.4},{"ad_id":26690417,"cpc":0},{"ad_id":22690359,"cpc":0}]}"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(1) "v"
        ["value"]=>
        string(4) "5.62"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `account_idAdvertising account ID required parameter, int (number)` А у вас нет.
2. Из документации:  `ad_id integer, required`  А вы строки отдаете.
3. И для чего используете `, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`? API  хочет массив объектов `dataSerialized JSON array of objects that describe changes in ads`.

Похоже что API, ждет:

```
// $data = json_encode(['data' => json_encode($data)]);
{
    "data": '[{"ad_id": 123,"cpc":4.4},{"ad_id": 321,"cpc":7.7}]',
    "account_id" : 123
}
```

А у вас:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {"ad_id": "123","cpc":4.4},
        "2": {"ad_id": "321","cpc":7.7}
    }
}
```

Comment: чтобы получить объект, `"JSON_FORCE_OBJECT - Выдавать объект вместо массива при использовании неассоциативного массива"`

Comment: @Hardc0re Обновил и дополнил ответ.

Comment: Переписал, но ошибка все равно осталась:
`string(151) "{"data":[{"ad_id":22981362,"cpc":4.4},{"ad_id":21975854,"cpc":4.4},{"ad_id":26721708,"cpc":4.4},{"ad_id":26790417,"cpc":0},{"ad_id":25690359,"cpc":0}]}"`

Comment: @Hardc0re А где "account_id"  ?

Comment: `account_id` передается , я скинул только часть ответа. Мой код работает для редактирования 1 объявления, но для нескольких - нет.

Comment: @Hardc0re если верить документам то `data` должна быть строка, я обновил ответ с ещё одним вариантом.

Comment: @Hardc0re Похоже со второй попытки, я угадал :).